# Graphs formed from union and join

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

If $G$ and $H$ are (simple, undirected) graphs, we can create a new graph in the following ways:

- Union: disjoint union of the two graphs
- Join: add an edge from every vertex of $G$ to every vertex of $H$.

I’m interested in graphs which can be formed from copies of the trivial graph with a single vertex using these operations.

For example, every complete graph can be created this way, but a path of length 4 cannot (I believe).

Is there a nice characterisation for graphs that can be created this way? Perhaps graphs avoiding a small number of forbidden subgraphs. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: These are particular cases of bipartite graphs : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph

Comment: Oh sorry I totally mixed up with another name that I don't remember

Comment: Ok you found the name :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably should have done some more research before posting! They are called [cographs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cograph.html).

Comment: *"7. G does not contain the path graph P_4 as an induced subgraph."* <<< Well-done :)

Comment: Do you also have the stability by complementary here?

Comment: Yes, we can instead define these as graphs formed by union and complement!